# constant arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, constants

This is a good old C array:

```
int a[10];
```

And this is a good old C array that is `const`:

```
const int b[10];
```

In C++, there seem to be two ways to define `std::array`s that are `const`:

```
std::array<const int, 10> c;
const std::array<int, 10> d;
```

Are these two definitions equivalent? If so, what is the idiomatic one? If not, what are the differences?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, the original `const int b[10];` is only useful when you can initialize the array, so both of the `std::array` examples don't work in practice.

## 1:

```
std::array<const int, 10> c;
```

This is the closest to `const int c[10];`. The problem is there will be no default constructor for it, and because the elements are not mutable, it's worthless to use this. You must provide some initialization for it in the constructor. As-is, it will give a compiler error because the default constructor did not initialize the elements.

This code means that `c` is mutable, but the elements themselves are not. In practice, however, there are no mutations on `c` that don't affect the elements.

## 2:

```
const std::array<int, 10> d;
```

This means `d` is not mutable, but the elements are of mutable type `int`. Because `const` will propagate to the members, it means the elements are still not mutable by the caller. Similar to the above example, you will need to initialize `d` because it's `const`.

**In practice, they will both behave similarly** with respect to mutability, because mutable operations on `array` always touch the elements.

Answer (score 7):

They aren't equivalent -- `c.reference` is `int&` whereas `d.reference` is `const int&` (not that you can use that syntax to access typedefs, but you could capture the type by template argument deduction and tell the difference).

But I'm pretty sure tenfour has the key observation, "there are no mutations on `c` that don't affect the elements". So as far as anything you actually do to the arrays is concerned they're the same, they just have different meta-data because of their different types.

The main case I can think of where it would make a difference is if you use the type itself in an interface (as opposed to taking an iterator or range template parameter). I'd say that when taking it as a pointer or reference parameter you *should* const-qualify the `array` type itself, since it costs you nothing and allows the caller to use your function whichever choice they made. You *may* const-qualify the element type, but whichever one you use is incompatible with the other one, so basically everyone has to agree which to use or else there will be some copying required. That requires active co-ordination as to style, I think, since I doubt that you'll get everyone in the world to agree which is best. `const int` probably has the better case, on the principle that you should `const` everything you can, but I expect `int` is what people will use who haven't thought about it at all, since they're used to all those C++03 containers that can't have a `const` value type.

Answer (score 5):

The upper definition allocates an array of constant integers on the stack, whereas the second one allocates a constant array of variable integers. In the first case, you must define the contents of the array when you declare it, since its content is constant and it cannot be modified later. I guess, the first second declaration will also generate something like

```
const std::array<const int,10> c;
```

since a static array is always allocated on the stack and the pointer to its first element cannot later be modified.

Comment: +1 although a static array is never allocated on the stack. A _fixed size_ array can be allocated on the stack (auto storage declspec) or in a global data segment (static storage declspec). Trivia: in `typedef int ints_t[10]; ints_t* ints = new ints_t();` is `ints` a fixed size array or a dynamic array ?

Comment: Both arrays require initialization when declared. IMHO, there is no difference between the two - they are exactly the same from an algorithmic and use perspective (practically, the iterators are the same; `const int*`). Frankly the best way to declare is as you say in the answer, `const std::array<const int, 10> c;` This makes it very specific, a const array of const ints.